# Alternating Direction Method of Multipliers

Tags: python, performance

This is a python implementation of the Alternating Direction Method of Multipliers - a method of constrained optimisation that is used widely in statistics (http://stanford.edu/~boyd/admm.html).

This is simplified version, specifically for the LASSO:

Given a sparse vector $$x \in R^n$$and matrix $$A \in R^{m \times n}$$ and noisy measurements $$y = Ax + e$$where $$e$$ is additive Gaussian white noise we can solve the following minimisation problem

$$
\hat{x} = \min_x ||y-Ax||_2^2 + \lambda||x||_1 
$$

to recover an estimate of $$x$$

The algorithm proceeds iteratively by calculating

$$ x^{k+1} = (A^TA + \rho I )^{-1}(A^Ty + \rho (z - u))$$
$$ z^{k+1} = \mathrm{sign}(\hat{x})\mathrm{max}\left(0, |x| - \frac{\lambda}{\rho}\right) $$

until some convergence criteria is met.

The implementation of the algorithm is below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import sqrt, log

def Sthresh(x, gamma):
    return np.sign(x)*np.maximum(0, np.absolute(x)-gamma/2.0)

def ADMM(A, y):

    m, n = A.shape
    w, v = np.linalg.eig(A.T.dot(A))
    MAX_ITER = 10000

    "Function to caluculate min 1/2(y - Ax) + l||x||"
    "via alternating direction methods"
    xhat = np.zeros([n, 1])
    zhat = np.zeros([n, 1])
    u = np.zeros([n, 1])

    "Calculate regression co-efficient and stepsize"
    l = sqrt(2*log(n, 10))
    rho = 1/(np.amax(np.absolute(w)))

    "Pre-compute to save some multiplications"
    AtA = A.T.dot(A)
    Aty = A.T.dot(y)
    Q = AtA + rho*np.identity(n)
    Q = np.linalg.inv(Q)

    i = 0

    while(i < MAX_ITER):

        "x minimisation step via posterier OLS"
        xhat = Q.dot(Aty + rho*(zhat - u))

        "z minimisation via soft-thresholding"
        zhat = Sthresh(xhat + u, l/rho)

        "mulitplier update"
        u = u + xhat - zhat

        i = i+1
    return zhat, rho, l

A = np.random.randn(50, 200)

num_non_zeros = 10
positions = np.random.randint(0, 200, num_non_zeros)
amplitudes = 100*np.random.randn(num_non_zeros, 1)
x = np.zeros((200, 1))
x[positions] = amplitudes

y = A.dot(x) + np.random.randn(50, 1)

xhat, rho, l = ADMM(A, y)

plt.plot(x, label='Original')
plt.plot(xhat, label = 'Estimate')

plt.legend(loc = 'upper right')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## A string is not a comment

A comment in the code starts with `#`. Even thought the strings you write seems to have no effect in the code, they are evaluated and created in memory (and thrown away right after) each time. Especially in the while loop.

Do not confuse yourself between [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) and comments.

## `l` is a really bad variable name.

I truly thought `l/rho` was `1/rho` at first and had a hard time mapping your code to the maths.

Given that:

- You don't seem to use the returned value for `rho` and `l`;
- You “only” need `rho` and the quotient `l/rho`;
- You don't need to recompute `l/rho` at each iterations.

I suggest you precompute using:

```
#Calculate regression co-efficient and stepsize
r = np.amax(np.absolute(w))
l_over_rho = sqrt(2*log(n, 10)) * r
rho = 1/r
```

and call `Sthresh(xhat + u, l_over_rho)` latter on. You also only need to `return zhat`.

Besides, you are dividing `l_over_rho` by `2.0` in `Sthresh`; on top of not seeing that anywhere in the maths, you should also incorporate it in the precomputation for a faster loop.

## A `for` loop is more pythonic

Since you don't need the value of `i` in your while loop, it is best to write:

```
for _ in xrange(MAX_ITER):
    #x minimisation step via posterier OLS
    xhat = Q.dot(Aty + rho*(zhat - u))
    #z minimisation via soft-thresholding
    zhat = Sthresh(xhat + u, l_over_rho)
    #mulitplier update
    u = u + xhat - zhat
```

to better emphasize the fact that you won't use the iteration value.

## Separate computation and presentation

I'd recommend creating a function for plotting the results and a function for your tests. That way, it would be easier to jump into an interactive session and test your function with alternatives input values:

```
def test():
    A = np.random.randn(50, 200)

    num_non_zeros = 10
    positions = np.random.randint(0, 200, num_non_zeros)
    amplitudes = 100*np.random.randn(num_non_zeros, 1)
    x = np.zeros((200, 1))
    x[positions] = amplitudes

    y = A.dot(x) + np.random.randn(50, 1)

    plot(x, ADMM(A,y)) #given that ADMM only 'return zhat' now

def plot(original, computed):
    plt.plot(original, label='Original')
    plt.plot(computed, label = 'Estimate')

    plt.legend(loc = 'upper right')

    plt.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

## [Optimization] Method lookups are faster with local variables

The `Sthresh` call incur overheads that you can easily remove since it is a one liner. In the same vein `Q.dot`, `np.sign`, `np.maximum`, and `np.absolute` have to be resolved at each loop iteration. You will save some time using local variable as alias to these functions:

```
Q_dot = Q.dot
sign = np.sign
maximum = np.maximum
absolute = np.absolute

for _ in xrange(MAX_ITER):
    #x minimisation step via posterier OLS
    xhat = Q_dot(Aty + rho*(zhat - u))
    #z minimisation via soft-thresholding
    u = xhat + u
    zhat = sign(u)*maximum(0, absolute(u)-l_over_rho/2.0) # do we even need the '/2.0' part ? see comment on 'l'
    #mulitplier update
    u = u - zhat
```

## Full modifications (with a tiny bit of variable renaming)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import sqrt, log

def ADMM(A, y):
    """Alternating Direction Method of Multipliers

    This is a python implementation of the Alternating Direction
    Method of Multipliers - a method of constrained optimisation
    that is used widely in statistics (http://stanford.edu/~boyd/admm.html).

    This is simplified version, specifically for the LASSO
    """

    m, n = A.shape
    A_t_A = A.T.dot(A)
    w, v = np.linalg.eig(A_t_A)
    MAX_ITER = 10000

    #Function to caluculate min 1/2(y - Ax) + l||x||
    #via alternating direction methods
    x_hat = np.zeros([n, 1])
    z_hat = np.zeros([n, 1])
    u = np.zeros([n, 1])

    #Calculate regression co-efficient and stepsize
    r = np.amax(np.absolute(w))
    l_over_rho = sqrt(2*log(n, 10)) * r / 2.0 # I might be wrong here
    rho = 1/r

    #Pre-compute to save some multiplications
    A_t_y = A.T.dot(y)
    Q = A_t_A + rho * np.identity(n)
    Q = np.linalg.inv(Q)
    Q_dot = Q.dot
    sign = np.sign
    maximum = np.maximum
    absolute = np.absolute

    for _ in xrange(MAX_ITER):
        #x minimisation step via posterier OLS
        x_hat = Q_dot(A_t_y + rho*(z_hat - u))
        #z minimisation via soft-thresholding
        u = x_hat + u
        z_hat = sign(u) * maximum(0, absolute(u)-l_over_rho)
        #mulitplier update
        u = u - z_hat

    return z_hat

def test(m=50, n=200):
    """Test the ADMM method with randomly generated matrices and vectors"""
    A = np.random.randn(m, n)

    num_non_zeros = 10
    positions = np.random.randint(0, n, num_non_zeros)
    amplitudes = 100*np.random.randn(num_non_zeros, 1)
    x = np.zeros((n, 1))
    x[positions] = amplitudes

    y = A.dot(x) + np.random.randn(m, 1)

    plot(x, ADMM(A,y))

def plot(original, computed):
    """Plot two vectors to compare their values"""
    plt.plot(original, label='Original')
    plt.plot(computed, label='Estimate')

    plt.legend(loc='upper right')

    plt.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

Comment: Thanks! I intended to use lambda for l, but that's already a keyword in python!

Comment: @TomKealy where names conflict it's conventional to append a trailing underscore, so you would use `lambda_` rather than `l` (which is a particularly bad single-letter name as it looks like `1` in many fonts - see also `0` vs. `O` in fonts without the `/` through zero).

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've changed it to mu now.